# npm WARN SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY when npm install vue-resource --save

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: this might be a question if we edit the title.
Check your package.json. Is there an entry under dependencies called vue-resource?

Comment: It's optional dependency, ignore it. You can do `npm install --no-optional` to not see this warn anymore.

Comment: thanks 
Your advice sounds right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get that warning for `fsevents` too on Linux. Seeing you're on Windows, You can safely ignore it. The package is targetting OSX.